# How to do a simple template data-bind in knockout?

Tags: jquery, html, data-binding, knockout.js

I am a newbie of knockout, I am trying to work out the a practise from plurasight, which bind a javascript array and display as a grid in the web page. Just can't figure out what mistake I made because I did what the video did.
Following is my code: Please can anyone give me a hand?

```
<div id="tagsList">
    <div>
         <h2>Tags</h2>

    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Tag" />
        <button>+ Add</button>
        <ul data-bind="template: {name: 'tagsTempl', foreach: tags}"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script id="tagsTempl" type="text/html">
    < li > < span > $ {
        Name
    }
    $ {
        (new Date).toLocaleTimeString()
    } < /span>
            <div>
                <a href="#" >Edit</a > < a href = "#" > Delete < /a>
            </div > < /li>
</script>

$(function () {


    var data = [{
        Id: 1,
        Name: "Ball Handling"
    }, {
        Id: 2,
        Name: "Passing"
    }, {
        Id: 3,
        Name: "Shooting"
    }, {
        Id: 4,
        Name: "Rebounding"
    }, {
        Id: 5,
        Name: "Transition"
    }, {
        Id: 6,
        Name: "Defense"
    }, {
        Id: 7,
        Name: "Team Offense"
    }, {
        Id: 8,
        Name: "Team Defense"
    }];

    var viewModel = {
        //data
        tags: ko.observableArray(data),
        tagToAdd: ko.observable(""),

        //behaviours
        addTag: function () {
            this.tags.push({
                Name: this.tagToAdd()
            });
            this.addTag("");
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

});
```

My code is http://jsfiddle.net/hanxuema/NTYLD/ as well

Thanks

Update

this is the page from course
[image]

this is what I made...
[image]

Comment: What's the problem? Please describe more clearly what you expected to happen and what actually happened. Also, why do you have all those extra spaces in your markup, and why do you have a `<script>` element that contains other elements?

Comment: `$` is not defined. You're not including jQuery for the document ready handler. See, when we remove the wrapping `$(function(){...})`, we get some output: http://jsfiddle.net/NTYLD/1/

Comment: @ahren  Thanks, however, your version still shows the html tags. Do you know how to make it displaying the actual data from js array, please see the picture in my update.

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks. Please see my update. Why the script element that contains other elements? I am not sure, this is the code from the video course.....

Comment: @nnnnnn - script elements that contain other elements, but have a `type="text/html"` or `type="template/html"` attribute are commonly used for templating. The browser ignores the contents of the `script` element, but you can still retrieve it for processing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change lot in your code.

1. Remove unwanted space from template "`<script id="tagsTempl" type="text/html">`"
2. You have to proper data-bind operation.

   - Do value data-bind against your input tag
   - Do Click data-bind against your **"+Add"**
   - Do text data-bind against span tag within your template
3. Since you are calling "addTag" from itself, this is possibly making infinite loop in addTag function. So change this.addTag("") into this.tagToAdd("").

Here working fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/NTYLD/4/

Note: Here I have removed jQuery's `$(function(){})` and template engine's syntax.